# Setting value of textbox in vb.net by only knowing its tabindex

Tags: vb.net, textbox, tabindex

On a form I have 100 textboxes. All these are ordered from 0 to 99 by the TabIndex, so you can tabulate trough all of them.

I need to set up that when I change the value of an even TabIndex, the cellbox with the next TabIndex gets the same value.
So if for example I change the value of `textbox6` then `textbox7` gets the same value.

This code does it only for even textboxes.

```
Private Sub Value_Changed(.....) Handles textbox0.TextChanged, textbox2.TextChanged etc...
....
End Sub
```

My problem is that I have no idea on how I can set the value for the textbox with the tabindex = tabindex+1.

any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved with the "getnextcontrol" function!

```
        Dim txt As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        Dim txt2 As TextBox
        txt2 = GetNextControl(sender, True)
        txt2.Text = txt.text
```

Comment: Excellent, so many solutions around the web suggest iterating through all controls, this is much better, thanks!